# How to set different background colors for several input submit forms(HTML)?

Tags: html, css, forms, background-color

I would like to ask how set different background colors for several input submit forms?
I have more input forms in HTML:

```
<div class="first">
<form method="post">
<input name="first" type="submit" value="one">
</form> 
</div> 


<div class="second">
<form method="post">
<input name="second" type="submit" value="two">
</form>
</div>

<div class="third">
<form method="post">
<input name="third" type="submit" value="three">
</form>
</div>
```

And I would like to set color of first of them as red, second green and third blue.

I tried to use indicate in css by div class.
But it will be mean that all the line will be colored by red.

```
.first{
background-color: red;
}
.... and so on
```

And I can´ use indication *input[type=submit]* too, because it will be valid from all submit forms.

```
input[type=submit]{
background-color: red;
}
```

So how to indicate every submit form with his name?
Thank you

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you are trying to achieve. To me you are saying, that you want different colors for your form background, but don't want everything inside that form in the same color?

Comment: It *sounds* like you are saying `.first{background-color: red;} .second{background-color: green;} .third{background-color: blue;}` does not give you your desired result.  What *is* your desired result?

Comment: `.first input {...}`, `.second input {...}, etc...See [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) on MDN.

Comment: @Zak Yes, this: https://imgur.com/XzQkhwm

Comment: @AmauryHanser Thank´s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am understanding your question.  You want just the `input` `background-color` vs the the entire `div`

If that is the case ..  Either give the `input` the `class` names you have specified for the divs  ... OR call the input by it's `name` [SELECTOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors): IE

```
input[name="first"] {
    background-color: red;
}
input[name="second"] {
    background-color: green;
}
input[name="third"] {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If that is too ambiguous, you can also "drill down": IE

```
.first input {
    background-color: red;
}
.second input {
    background-color: blue;
}
.third input {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Both will achieve the same result.  You can also give your inputs an `id` **RECOMMENDED**

```
<input id="third" name="third" type="submit" value="three">
```

Then call it by `id` with `#`:

```
#third {
    background-color: green;
}
```